# how to install stuff on Linux Mint?

Tags: installation, linux-mint

I have this tar.gz package, which contains just some files, no explaination to install or so. How can i install it, so i have like shortcuts, and it is in my Menu, etc.

Comment: You should give details of the package (perhaps a link to the relevant website, or at least the name of the app/tool/whatever the package is for) then we might be able to give more specific advice than "see if it already ina  repo" or "did the website have any instructions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux Mint is an Ubuntu derivative, so you should be able to use Synaptic to search if the program you're trying to install is already packaged for it. If you can't find it, try to search PPAs for a development repository for it.

What is the program actually? Does it need to be compiled, or is it just files to copy?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install eclipse`. Package managers are amazing. Run `dpkg -s eclipse` to see if it installed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended that you install the programs from the package manager.
Nevertheless to install it, first extract the files

```
tar xvfz package-name.tar.gz (for gzipped files) 
tar xvfj package-name.tar.bz2 (for bzipped files)
```

Examine the contents, if there's a .sh or a .bin file then its probably an installer, so assign Execute rights

```
chmod u+x name-of-file.extension
```

& run it

```
./name-of-file.extension
```

If it contains sources, then you need to compile them. Follow the INSTALL or README file, for more info, Generally, the steps involve:

```
cd /path/to/directory/of/source
```

and then cofigure,

```
./configure
```

Next, run the make file,

```
make
```

Follow it up by switch to root & install

```
su root
make install
```

A more detailed look, including possible error messages that you might encounter is [mentioned here](http://sathyasays.com/2008/07/24/how-to-compile-a-program-from-source-code-installing-from-source/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the tar.gz file is the source of the application you want to install. First check if the program already available as a Linux Mint package using the Application Installer (Synaptic). Perhaps [these tips](http://linuxgazette.net/137/lazar.html) might help for Linux Mint.

If you would like to install the source tar.gz archives, they usually have a file called INSTALL or README that contains instructions for installation.